# Is A Particular Type of Corrosion a Proper Noun?

Tags: capitalization

There is a particular type of corrosion called 'stress corrosion cracking'.

Is this a proper or common noun?

Comment: To be pedantic.  It isn't a form of corrosion, it is a form of cracking caused by corrosion.

Comment: If it were a proper noun, you would have spelled it "Stress Corrosion Cracking".

Comment: Try it without the qualifier words. Is `cracking' a noun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a noun phrase built up of a base (*cracking*) and an attributive noun phrase (*stress corrosion*). *Stress corrosion* itself is a combination of the base *corrosion* and the attributive noun *stress*). Attributive nouns  describe the nouns they're paired with, so *stress corrosion* describes the cause of the *cracking* ([ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-attributive-noun-1689012)).

It is not a proper noun, defined as

> a noun belonging to the class of words used as names for specific or unique individuals, events, or places, and may include real or fictional characters and settings ([ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/proper-noun-grammar-1691690)),

because stress corrosion cracking does not refer to a specific event by name (ex. The Battle of the Bulge) but rather to a general physical phenomenon (ex. a pitched battle). Even if you decide to make an acronym out of it, like SCC (which the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_corrosion_cracking) uses a lot), it's still a common noun phrase. (Ex. ATM, or automated teller machine, is a common noun phrase referring to the kind of machine, not the trademarked name of a specific design like a [Nixdorf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nixdorf_Computer) ATM.)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is a descriptive term. The only terms for conditions or materials that are proper nouns (and therefore capitalized) include actual names, such as "Stockholm syndrome" or "Venetian plaster."